# Where is mailer.py?

Tags: python, email, svn

I'm setting up a subversion server and need to send email to users on post commit.

I can see a sample post-commit hook which includes "mailer.py".

That file doesn't seem to exist.

I can see lots of people via Google who have set this up, and want answers about more complex setups. I can't see any info about where mailer.py is, and how to actually use it.

Can anyone direct me how to set up the basics?

Comment: `apt-file find mailer.py` command shows `subversion-tools: /usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/mailer/mailer.py` i.e., you might need `sudo apt-get install subversion-tools` to get `mailer.py`.

Comment: Ah, good call - thanks. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Oh, and if a girl called Pris asks you for some help - run ;)

Comment: my guess is that `mailer.py` along is not enough to send email. But if you've tested it and it works then you could post your steps as an answer. [It is explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 2):

Install subversion tools

```
 sudo apt-get install subversion-tools
```

Then install the SSMTP

```
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
```

Then add your username, password and ssmtp mail server port in your ssmtp.conf file (/etc/ssmtp/ssmpt.conf)

```
  /usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/mailer/mailer.py
  /usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/mailer/mailer.conf
```

Edit the lines in mailer.conf file.
Add your username, password, ssmtp mail server port number, to address and from address.

I think this is you want...

Answer (score 0):

## How to install mailer

```
sudo apt-get install python-mailer
```

The [mailer pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mailer/0.7) has some helpful usage examples.

Comment: Thanks for the quick info - I just installed it, I'm still trying to find mailer.py though. And when I find it, I have no idea what to put in the config file. I suppose I could learn python and take the script apart, but it seems a bit extreme to just set up a subversion server! I'm going to try to see if I can do this in another language I already know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own mailer.py to solve this following this post:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Email

I placed my own mailer.py in a directory created alongside the hooks in /path_to_repo/hooks/.

Then I passed that path as the program to run in post-commit, as this is the hook I wanted the email to be triggered from.